# XSLT 2.0 - Template Matching With Contains()

Tags: templates, xslt, contains, matching

I'm wondering if it is possible to write a template match with the `contains()` function.

I have a document that has multiple elements that need to be renamed to a common element. All of the following need to be renamed to just OP: OP1.2, OP7.3, OP2.4, OP5.6`, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use `contains()` inside of a predicate filter in the match criteria for elements.

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(local-name(),'OP')]>
  <OP>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </OP>
</xsl:template>
```

You could also use [`starts-with()`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_starts-with.html)

```
*[starts-with(local-name(),'OP')]
```

If you are using XSLT 2.0 you could use the [`matches()`](http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-XPath_2.html#Functions~matches) function, which supports REGEX patterns for more complex matching.

```
*[matches(local-name(),'^OP')]
```

Comment: Can we provide multiple values to match? like : match="*[contains(local-name(),'OP1|OP2|OP3')]

Comment: @Sishant Mishra yes, you can. The second parameter is a regex pattern, so as long as it's a valid regex it will work.