# I want to match a template to elements based on name ends-with

Tags: xml, xslt

I've spent quite a bit time trying to figure this out and the failure provides no clues as to what's wrong. I'm experimenting with xslt for a project. Obviously, I'm trying to use 2.0 and this is from VS 2012, c# fw 4.5

For this test I want to replace the value of any xxxSK elements with nothing if the value is 0.

This would apply for elements like: , , , etc.

If I target the bottom template to "SK" it is correctly applied to all  templates. But I wanted the "ends with" logic (or "contains" in this example). When I run this I get a useless message on the call to Transform():

```
System.InvalidProgramException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233030
Message=Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
Source=System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.1
StackTrace:
   at <xsl:apply-templates>(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator )
   at Root(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
   at Execute(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlSequenceWriter results)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList arguments, XmlWriter results, XmlResolver documentResolver)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList arguments, Stream results)
   at Test.XsltTest.Test(Drug drug, String styleSheet) in c:\DEV\Local Projects\_JunkTempWork\AppToSQLDataTransferTesting\Test\XsltTest.cs:line 34
   at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\DEV\Local Projects\_JunkTempWork\AppToSQLDataTransferTesting\Test\Program.cs:line 28
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

[A similar question was asked here][1], but I can't get that answer to work for me.

Here is my stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[matches(name(), '.*SK')]">  <--- ORIGINAL QUESTION
<xsl:template match="*[substring(name(), string-length() -1) = 'SK']" priority="9"> <--- NEW BASED ON ANSWER

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;New</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>

  <xsl:if test=". != '0'">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/New</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's my test code (the model is just a simple test class):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Test.Models;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace Test
{
    public class XsltTest
    {
        public string Test(Drug drug, string styleSheet)
        {
            //ListResources(); return string.Empty;

            // Serialize
            Console.WriteLine("Serialized:");
            string xml = XmlSerialization.Serialize(drug);

            // Load into XML DOC
            var xd = new XmlDocument();
            xd.LoadXml(xml);

            // Load XSLT DOC
            var xslt = GetTransform(styleSheet);

            using (var stm = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Transform!
                xslt.Transform(xd, null, stm);

                // Fetch the results
                stm.Position = 1;
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(stm))
                {
                    string result = "\nSource:\n\n" + xml + "\n\nOutput:\n\n" + sr.ReadToEnd();
                    return result;
                }
            }


        }

        private void ListResources()
        {
            string[] resources = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
            foreach (string r in resources)
                Console.WriteLine("Resource: {0}", r);
        }

        private XslCompiledTransform GetTransform(string styleSheet)
        {
            if (!Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames().Contains(styleSheet))
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Stylesheet {0} not found.", styleSheet));

            using (Stream s = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(styleSheet))
            {
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(s))
                {
                    XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
                    transform.Load(reader);
                    return transform;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

UPDATE: Thanks to a response I got it partially working. Can anyone see why it's not matching on all the elements? As you can see it matches on only 2 of the elements, and even then I can't see a pattern of why it chose those, but not the others.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Drug xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SK>0</SK>
  <MasterSK>0</MasterSK>
  <Name>Sample Drug Name</Name>
  <DrugRoutes>
    <DrugRoute>
      <SK>202</SK>
      <Name>Intravenous</Name>
    </DrugRoute>
    <DrugRoute>
      <SK>203</SK>
      <Name>Oral</Name>
    </DrugRoute>
    <DrugRoute>
      <SK>0</SK>
      <Name>New Route</Name>
    </DrugRoute>
  </DrugRoutes>
  <Flavor>Watermelon</Flavor>
</Drug>
```

And the results (for some reason it loses the formatting, clearly based on something I've done):

```
??<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Drug xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><NewSK>NULL</NewSK><MasterSK>0</MasterSK><Name>Sample Drug Name</Name><DrugRoutes><DrugRoute><S
K>202</SK><Name>Intravenous</Name></DrugRoute><DrugRoute><SK>203</SK><Name>Oral</Name></DrugRoute><DrugRoute><NewSK>NULL</NewSK><Name>New Route</Name></DrugRoute></DrugRoutes><Flavor>Watermelon</Flavo
r></Drug>
```

Comment: Not sure what happened to the link in the post. Here it is: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036169/xslt-2-0-template-matching-with-contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036169/xslt-2-0-template-matching-with-contains)

Comment: Do you know whether VS 2012, c# fw 4.5 supports XSLT 2.0? or just 1.0?

Comment: I've never heard of `XslCompiledTransform` supporting XSLT 2.0. Perhaps you should check out Saxon, or use the 1.0 approach to ends-with: `substring(name(), string-length(name()) - 1) = 'SK'`.

Comment: Oh good grief. It hadn't occurred to me the latest and greatest VS would not support a standard that I assume has been out for years. I half got it working, now. Strangely, it's being very selective in which elements it matches on. I'm going to try to edit the question to post the input XML and the output, hoping to learn why it's not matching on all, when I think it should. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "loses the formatting"? Can you show us your expected output?

Comment: Well as you can see in the final snippet (the result) the xml is a single string with no CR/LF. If I eliminate my "custom" tag it comes back more readable.

Comment: Yeah it's sad that XSLT 2.0 is not more widely supported, especially by mainstream tools like Microsoft's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, if an element whose name ends in "SK" has the value 0, you want to replace its content with a new value. Is that correct? If so, this will do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[. = '0']
                        [substring(name(), string-length(name()) -1) = 'SK']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text>This used to be 0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<Drug xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SK>This used to be 0</SK>
  <MasterSK>This used to be 0</MasterSK>
  <Name>Sample Drug Name</Name>
  <DrugRoutes>
    <DrugRoute>
      <SK>202</SK>
      <Name>Intravenous</Name>
    </DrugRoute>
    <DrugRoute>
      <SK>203</SK>
      <Name>Oral</Name>
    </DrugRoute>
    <DrugRoute>
      <SK>This used to be 0</SK>
      <Name>New Route</Name>
    </DrugRoute>
  </DrugRoutes>
  <Flavor>Watermelon</Flavor>
</Drug>
```

It looks like you were doing some hacky stuff in an attempt to change the element names, but if you want to replace elements with new names, you can do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[. = '0']
                        [substring(name(), string-length(name()) -1) = 'SK']">
    <xsl:element name="New{name()}">
      <xsl:text>This used to be 0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This results in:

```
<Drug xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <NewSK>This used to be 0</NewSK>
  <NewMasterSK>This used to be 0</NewMasterSK>
  <Name>Sample Drug Name</Name>
  <DrugRoutes>
    <DrugRoute>
      <SK>202</SK>
      <Name>Intravenous</Name>
    </DrugRoute>
    <DrugRoute>
      <SK>203</SK>
      <Name>Oral</Name>
    </DrugRoute>
    <DrugRoute>
      <NewSK>This used to be 0</NewSK>
      <Name>New Route</Name>
    </DrugRoute>
  </DrugRoutes>
  <Flavor>Watermelon</Flavor>
</Drug>
```

Comment: Considering this was my first ever attempt at XSLT, I'm sure everything here is hacky! Originally that hack was simply to write out the tag name, but I added the rename just to prove that it was in fact matching. I will try your code Monday morning. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I'm trying to get your solution to work, but I'm still having mixed success. While it matches the first SK and the SK in the second drug route object, it doesn't match and replace the MasterSK. I've looked at it many times and I can't see a difference between your example and what I have. My input XML shown in the question is still the same. You can see that the MasterSK right below the first SK is '0', just as the SK is, yet it's not matched.

Comment: I got it working finally. My bad. I wasn't passing name() into string-length. Thanks again - this has really helped me out.